# Can this condition using std::is_same<> be evaluated at compile time?

Tags: c++, c++11, compile-time

I know that `constexpr` functions don't have to be evaluated at compile time, but they are if it is possible. Is the condition of the following `if` evaluated at compile time or not?

```
template <typename T> inline std::string toString(const T& arg, int decPlaces) 
{ 
    if (!std::is_same<T, float>::value && !std::is_same<T, double>::value)
        return std::to_string(arg);
    // Else go on strip digits after decimal point
}
```

I know that in C++17 there is `if constexpr` which guarantees evaluation at compile time, but I'm just wondering whether it might be evaluated at compile time in this case because the `bool` returned from `is_same` is `constexpr`. Such as in a situation when C++17 cannot be used.

Comment: @水飲み鳥 Oh, you're right. I thought it was C++14 :-(

Comment: Oh I didn't know the _v version itself is C++17 itself. My question is if you're using a compiler that's not using C++17 whether it can basically cut the code after that even without without the if constexpr. Angew says it can/might.

Comment: Note that I edited the code quite heavily, since it wasn't matching your question text. If my edit is incorrect, please revert it.

Comment: The standard doesn't define what "at compile time" means.

Comment: Actually, `constexpr` *variables* **have to be initialized** with compile-time constants (e.g.: a `constexpr` expression), `constexpr` *expressions* **can be used** in compile-time contexts, and `constexpr` functions **can be evaluated** at compile time when possible, otherwise they are evaluated at run time. I've already replaced *expressions* by *functions* in your question, but editing it further would be putting too many words of my own into your mouth, which may change what you want to express.

Comment: Your if condition is runtime, but can be optimized.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider this slightly modified version of your code (so that the control flow cannot reach the end of such a non-`void` function):

```
template <typename T> inline std::string toString(const T& arg, int decPlaces) 
{ 
    if (!std::is_same<T, float>::value && !std::is_same<T, double>::value)
        return std::to_string(arg);

    return ""; // <-- added
}
```

By explicitly instantiating your template function for `T=float`:

```
template std::string toString<float>(const float&, int);
```

and then compiling it with `g++` *6.4.0* and `-O2` enabled, the following assembly code is generated for the *x86* platform:

```
__Z8toStringIfESsRKT_i:
    pushl   %ebx
    subl    $40, %esp
    movl    48(%esp), %ebx
    leal    31(%esp), %eax
    movl    $LC0, 4(%esp)
    movl    %eax, 8(%esp)
    movl    %ebx, (%esp)
    call    __ZNSsC1EPKcRKSaIcE
    addl    $40, %esp
    movl    %ebx, %eax
    popl    %ebx
    ret $4
```

There is nothing *conditional* in the code above.

So, for this compiler and platform, the condition is actually evaluated at compile time. You can proceed analogously for your targeted compiler and platform.

Comment: I don't understand assembly. What would a conditional look like? A jump if?

Comment: @Zebrafish a `j`-something (jump) instruction, such as `je`, `jz` or `jne`.

Comment: In general, you should look not only for *conditional jumps*, but also for any *conditional instruction* like `setCC` or `cmovCC`, being `CC` a *Conditional Code* (i.e.: `e`/`z`, `ne`, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be sure, inspect the generated assembly. However, it's extremely that likely the compiler will indeed replace the `if` by an unconditional `return` (if `T` is a `float` or `double`), or remove it altogether (otherwise). This is a fairly basic optimisation.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to make sure all code paths for `T` being `float` or `double` and others will need to be valid at the same time for it to compile. If the code in the `if` and `else` would not be valid for a specific type, you run into errors.

For the exact optimisations applied, you would need to inspect the assembly code.